# What is this specific transformer configuration called?

Tags: 24v-transformer

[image]

See the top of this transformer, I think the 120V wire comes from the top.

I want to get a new 24VAC transformer to support my Google nest, but I couldn’t find any transformer with this specific connection at the top.

What is it called? Is there a standard name to this?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=doorbell+transformer&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: FYI 24 VAC is typical for HVAC, but 16 VAC is typical for doorbells.

Comment: The one in stock at my local hardware store is tapped so you can get 6, 18, and 24 volts all from the same transformer. Handy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly all bell transformers of this style have a threaded nipple or bracket on one side that connects to the electrical box. Your local hardware or big box store should have one.

Comment: Thanks I thought it’s some special bracket. I’ll just buy one with threaded nipple and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a doorbell transformer to me.